# GAE Bulkloader isn't working for me. Get a 302 error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

Cannot upload/download entities from Cloud Datastore.

In the past I used the bulkloader utility to upload/download entities to the Datastore.  Now when I try I get a error traceback ending with: oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

I've followed the suggestions on that the link, but then I get this error:
2019-10-07 08:18:28,017 INFO client.py:546 Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
2019-10-07 08:18:28,246 INFO client.py:804 Refreshing access_token 
Error 302: 
--- begin server output ---
--- end server output ---

I've tried including the --oauth2 key with both --oauth2_access_token and the ---oauth2_refresh_token (all keys have Owner Permissions) but I keep getting the 302 refresh error.

c:\python27\python appcfg.py download_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --filename=MyTable.csv --kind=MyTable --url http://google.appspot.com/remote_api --application=google

INFO client.py:804 Refreshing access_token 
Error 302:

Does anyone have a suggestion what I might try to get this to work?  Is anyone still using the bulk-loader?

Comment: To my knowledge it's a thing of the past and not available anymore. But you can upload your files to Cloud Storage even with a free bucket and import / read your CSV data.

Comment: yea, I setup a bucket and tried downloading the data.  Was able to transfer data to the bucket, and then transfer the data from the bucket to my pc.  But the files I ended up with are a mess.  At first I thought they were zip format, but  that's not it.  No idea what format I ended up with - I suspect it's some kind of backup format.  Not very useful for my purposes.  I haven't tried to upload a CSV, but if I can't download existing data I'm not gonna invest in uploading any data.

Comment: I don'y know what you have done but you can use upload and download files in the storage browser UI in almost any format. I never hit a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is in the document "Exporting and Importing Entities" https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities

Comment: Well.. Not really. I just want to export my data as a CSV - like the CSV's I originally used to import it.  But the link you provided clearly says that the output is (as I suspected) some kind of backup format - apparently called "Level DB Log Format".  So I'm still hunting for a way to download my data as a CSV.

Comment: You are right, now the option of exporting to CSV is switched off, that's  why you are getting this error, you can see it in the document Backing Up and Restoring( https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring?csw=1#Creating_Exporter_Classes ), but you can apply a workaround adding an extra step after download the Level DB Log Format file, converting it programmatically to CSV, here is a snipet of code as an example to achieve it https://gist.github.com/maxrp/3d5d513b3bdb185b16219ecd6e18885f

Comment: I shouldn't have to write a program to restore a capability that existed previously.  Also, It's not clear to me HOW this could be use to "upload" a CSV either.

Comment: I am agree with you, but at this moment that tool which you are making reference is switched off, so there isn't at the moment a direct way to do it, if you want to upload a file you have to reverse the process converting the CSV file to Level DB Log Format. On the other hand, there is a feature request which you can mark as affected in case it adjust to your need or in the same link you can open your own feature request describing what you need https://issuetracker.google.com/121343096